# Ping not working while curl working

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I'm on a Ubuntu Xenial VM and I'm bugged by this phenomenon:

- ping doesn't work, even on an IP address (100% packets loss)
- all commands that do remote connections like git, pip or curl do work

Example:

```
admindev@rxlemdevdatlp01:~/dir$ curl -O https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unix/Img/logo.svg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8419  100  8419    0     0  18945      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18919
admindev@rxlemdevdatlp01:~/dir$ ping -c 1 cdn.sstatic.net
PING cdn.sstatic.net (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- cdn.sstatic.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

How do you explain this? It's as if the machine would reject ICMP replies...

Comment: Try 1st ping localhost, or ping some machines in the local network, aka fast path.
More info: https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/ping-icmp-and-priority/td-p/611529

Comment: What kind of firewall setting do you use / does the network your computer is connected to use? Some firewalls are configured to drop ICMP traffic.

Comment: ping localhost works! I thought about firewall blocking packets, but running "sudo iptables -L" doesn't show anything linked with ICMP. But I'm not used to such outputs:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: `git`, `pip` and `curl` might be using a proxy, and `ping` couldn't. If your are using a VM, what about network configuration at host level ?

Comment: How is the proxy configured under Linux? The variable http_proxy is unset. The problems I experience are from within the VM. On my Windows workstation, I can of course run a ping.

Comment: It could also just be that the target does not respond to ping requests. The firewall on the remote side could filter it.

Comment: It's not the case, you can try for yourself (the server cdn.sstatic.net is that of stackexchange).